# makefile fails when creating object file for inner directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

In the current directory I have the following files:

```
election.c election.h extended_map.c extended_map.h main.c test_utilities.c utilities.c utilities.h
```

Plus I have an inner folder inside the current one called `mtm_map` which includes `map.c map.h`

I have created a makefile which works fine when running:

```
make main.o
make extended_map.o
make election.o
make utilities.o
make clean
```

but fails when running:

```
-bash-4.2$ make map.o
cc    -c -o map.o map.c
map.c: In function ‘getIndexOfKey’:
map.c:36:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++)
     ^
map.c:36:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
map.c: In function ‘initializeElements’:
map.c:59:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i=initial_index;i<last_index;i++)
     ^
map.c: In function ‘mapCopy’:
map.c:165:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++)
     ^
map.c: In function ‘mapGet’:
map.c:239:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (int i = 0; i < map->size; i++)
     ^
make: *** [map.o] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o ./mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror
$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c ./mtm_map/map.h election.h test_utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
map.o: ./mtm_map/map.c ./mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h ./mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
election.o: election.c election.h ./mtm_map/map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
    $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that? Please Note I want map.o to be created inside the current directory (not inside `mtm_map`)

Comment: Please, read the compiler messages.  That's a compilation problem, not a make error.  You have several syntax errors in your code, and the messages explain well enough what is the problem in your `map.c` file (at line 36)

Comment: @LuisColorado You're not reading carefully enough.  The problem is not in the code, the problem is in the compile line: it's missing all the compiler flags.  In particular, it's missing the `-c99` compiler flag which tells the compiler use the ISO C99 standard when compiling code.  The reason the compiler flags are missing is because `make` is using its built-in rule for creating an object file, not the rule in the makefile.  The only reason that could be is if the OP was `cd`'d into the `mtm_map` subdirectory before running make.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `make` will read both `Makefile` and `makefile` so the capitalization of the name is not the problem.  See my other comment and my answer.

Comment: @MadScientist, I've read it carefully, and I have answered the question.  The problem is indeed in the makefile, as you state, but I have written an answer, and I focus on the problem there.  The OP asks about makefile, but then shows the compilation of a simple file, that doesn't use the `COMP_FLAG` at all, so probably he has misnamed the `Makefile` or he is in a different directory. He is using default rules to compile map.c into map.o, and they use `CFLAGS`, not `COMP_FLAG`.

Comment: You said _you have several syntax errors in your code_.  That's not true.  The code is fine... it's just written to the C99 standard.  I already explained in my answer (likely) why this happened (running `make` from within the `mtm_map` directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that the error you show came from running the makefile you provided.

When you ran `make map.o` did you run it from the upper directory, or did you run it from within the `mtm_map` directory?  If the latter that would explain it.

You have a number of problems here.  First, if you really do want the `map.o` file to exist in the top-level directory then your setting of `OBJS` is wrong; this:

```
OBJS = main.o ./mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be:

```
OBJS = main.o map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
```

Second, you should always use `-o $@` (I believe this has already been mentioned at least twice in similar questions you've asked on SO over the last few days) in your rules.

And finally, you should use `$<` not `$*.c` when you reference the source file in your rules; the former expands to the first prerequisite including its full path.  The `$*` in the latter expands to only the stem, which won't include the path.

So your makefile should look like this:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = main.o map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
EXEC = election
DEBUG_FLAG = -DNDEBUG
COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror
$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
main.o: main.c ./mtm_map/map.h election.h test_utilities.h
        $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -o $@ $<
map.o: ./mtm_map/map.c ./mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
        $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -o $@ $<
extended_map.o: extended_map.c extended_map.h ./mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
        $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -o $@ $<
election.o: election.c election.h ./mtm_map/map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
        $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -o $@ $<
utilities.o: utilities.c utilities.h
        $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) -o $@ $<
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Comment: The whole issue was cause of $*.c

Comment: Nope... `$<` is **only used in automatic rules**, not in explicit rules with commands.  He has included the source code, so the automatic compilation rule is not selected.  He has to use the `$*.c`, but see better my answer.  It is better not to rename the `CFLAGS` variable to something, as he is getting a compilation error, that should be avoided with `-std=c99`.  The setting of `./mtm_map/map.o` as posted is correct.  Make should use the full path if you include it in the rule.

Comment: @LuisColorado you are not correct.  In GNU make, which the OP is using, `$<` is well-defined for every rule even explicit rules.  The above makefile is 100% correct (although it could be greatly simplified--this is the OPs third question on this same subject so I wanted to just get it working for them) when using GNU make.  If you want to write a strictly POSIX conforming make then you can't use _either_ `$<` or `$*` in the recipes as both are defined only for suffix rules in POSIX.  The makefile wuld have to write out the source files explicitly in the recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Your Make is not using properly the `$(COMP_FLAG)` you define in it:

There's normally a `CFLAGS` variable to do it with the implicit rules to compile source files, so I'll rewrite your `Makefile` in order to eliminate a lot of redundant code you have included in it:

```
# I use the ?= operator, so you can redefine the compiler with make CC=clang ...
CC       ?= gcc 
EXEC      = election
TOCLEAN   = $(EXEC)

# NDEBUG is a compilation option, not a linking one.  The purpose of MY_CFLAGS is
# to allow you to define extra CFLAGS to be used on source code compilation.
CFLAGS    = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG $(MY_CFLAGS)
 
OBJS      = main.o mtm_map/map.o extended_map.o election.o utilities.o
# you can add files to clean in a more complex makefile
TOCLEAN  += $(OBJS)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)
clean:
    rm -f $(TOCLEAN)

# Extra dependencies (the dependency a.o : a.c is automatic)
main.o: mtm_map/map.h election.h utilities.h
mtm_map/map.o: mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
extended_map.o: extended_map.h mtm_map/map.h utilities.h
election.o: election.h mtm_map/map.h extended_map.h utilities.h
utilities.o: utilities.h
```

This should build correctly your project.

## Note

If you decide that some of the source files must reside in other directories than the one you have the Makefile in, then you have to consider if you want the object files in your directory or in the directory where the sources are.  I have followed what I thought was what you want (building all source files in *this* directory can lead to name clashes, as two files in different directories can have the same name) but then you have to use the paths to the objects also (as I have used here)

There's another alternative, is to make a build directory, so all the files are built in a replica or the hierarchy used in sources.  But this has some other drawbacks, as you must rewrite the automatic rules, in order to rebuild the directory structure you had before trying to put files in it.

Comment: The OP specifically wanted `map.o` to be in the current directory (along with all other object files), not the subdirectory, so this makefile does not match the requested behavior.

Comment: Just a note: you do not have to use `?=` to allow variables to be assigned on the command line.  Running `make CC=gcc` will override `CFLAGS` in the makefile even if it is assigned with `=` or `:=`.  Command line settings always override in-makefile settings.  Using `?=` will allow a `CC=gcc` assignment in the environment to override the makefile, though (makefile variables take precedence over environment variables, by default).

Comment: I do not have to use, but I use it to allow the make command to override the compiler.  Of course, if you override the compiler, you probably need to override the options also.  Thas't true, but this are only recommendations.  The `Makefile` provided in the answer has been tested and works. If you use `CC=gcc` then you cannot override the compiler from the command line.

Comment: The OP doesn't say anything about wanting the `map.o` in other place.  He shows just what he has, but he is naming `map.o` on `make` invocation, then he is using `map.o` as target, while in dependencies, he states clearly that `map.c` is in a different directory.  Ah he is calling `make map.o`, most probably he is trying to execute make not in the base directory, but in the `mtm_map` subdirectory in which he has no `makefile` in the `mtm_map` subdirectory, and that's the reason he doesn't use a `Makefile` at all (just default rules, that don't use `COMP_FLAG`.

Comment: You are wrong.  Assigning a variable on the make command line, as in `make CC=gcc`, will override an assignment like `CC = cc` in the makefile.  Try it.  For more info the precedence of make variable assignment, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html

Comment: The OP _did_ state where they wanted the object file: see the last sentence in the question: _Please Note I want map.o to be created inside the current directory (not inside `mtm_map`)_

Comment: The OP probably has created (or modified) a `Makefile` has put it on the base directory, and then has tried to create the `map.o` file.  As the paths in the makefile don't show a rule to make `mtm_map/map.o`, he has changed directory there, and tried to compile it (using `make`) there.  As there's no makefile there, the compiling options are defaullt (none) and that's the reason of the compiling error.

Comment: I agree, that's what I said in my answer yesterday: _When you ran make map.o did you run it from the upper directory, or did you run it from within the `mtm_map` directory? If the latter that would explain it._ and in my comments above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213620/discussion-between-luis-colorado-and-madscientist).